# Compiling x64 dll from x86 using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am compiling some external C++ code into a dll using Visual Studio 2008.
The code is wrapped in extern "C".

Since I am cross compiling, creating a 64 bit dll on my 32 bit machine;
I am using x64 as "Active solution platform" in the "Configuration Manager".

My dll compiles and links successfully. However when I open it in Dependency Walker (depends.exe) I notice something strange:
My dll is marked as 64 bit. My dll however depends on C:\windows\system32\ntdll.dll and C:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll which are 32 bit!
As a result Dependency Walker gives me the following errors:
"Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found."

What is going wrong here?

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: For backward compatibility on a 64 bit machine the files from system32 are actually the 64 bit ones. So on a 64 bit machine ntdll.dll and kernel32.dll would be actually 64 bit versions. The 32 versions are located in SysWow64.

Answer (score 2):

Dependency walker gives you that error because the dll files in `system32` *on your 32 bit system* are 32 bits. If you run it on a 64 bit version of Windows it will work fine.

Perhaps the misunderstanding comes from the name of `system32`? It doesn't necessarily contain 32 bit files - it contains files matching the bit size of the operating system, so on 32 bit Windows `sytem32` contains 32 bit dlls, and on 64 bit Windows `system32` contains 64 bit dlls.

It gets more complicated though - 64 bit Windows can run 32 bit processes, and if a 32 bit process accesses system32 on a 64 bit version of Windows, that access it gets redirected to the `SysWOW64` (yes `system32` contains 64 bit dlls and `SysWOW64` contains 32 bit dlls).

Comment: The error message is actually a confirmation that the compiled DLL is indeed 64-bit, as it can't find all the necessary imports in a 32-bit DLL, which is quite logical, because a 32-bit DLL has no x64 contents.

Answer (score 1):

Your DLL depends on `ntdll.dll` and `kernel32.dll`. Dependency Walker tries to find them according to lookup rule of the [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28VS.85%29.aspx) function. And it finds them in `system32` directory, but on 32-bit system they are 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Use 64 bit version of Dependency Walker to open your 64 bit version of dll's. You will no longer see the error message, "Error: Modules with different CPU types were found", if your modules are properly compiled for x64.

Comment: Except he mentioned his OS is 32-bit, which means he can't run the 64 bit version of dependency walker.